# Typescript function parameter and return parameter different

Tags: arrays, typescript, function, types

Hi guys I'm working through a Leetcode problem and they've supplied the function line of code. I read it as function romanToInt takes a string variable, and the function returns a number variable.

I'm trying to take the s string, split it, and then append it to an array so i can iterate through it. The error I'm getting is:

> Type '(...items: string[]) => number' is not assignable to type
> '[]'.ts(2322)

There is something I'm doing wrong with the types.

Any help will be appreciated.

```
function romanToInt(s: string): number {
    
    let sArray:[] = s.split(',').unshift;

    let result:number = 0;
```

Comment: unshift returns number. and you are not calling unshift but getting the unshift function from array prototype

Answer (score 0):

```
let sArray:[] = s.split(',').unshift;
Type '(...items: string[]) => number' is not assignable to type '[]'.ts(2322)
```

This error means that you are trying to assign `(...items: string[]) => number` (a function type)`to`[]` (an array type). This is invalid.

One thing it's telling you is that you forgot to invoke the function. So let's add some parentheses.

```
let sArray:[] = s.split(',').unshift();
// Type 'number' is not assignable to type '[]'.(2322)
```

But as you can see, there is a new error.

The docs for `unshift` say this:

> Inserts new elements at the start of an array, and returns the new length of the array.

So `unshift()` returns the length of the array. This is a `number`. And `number` cannot be assigned to an array.

---

At this point I'm not sure what you are trying to do, so it's hard to advise more.

But if all you want to do is:

> take the `s` string, split it, and then <strike>append it to an array so i can</strike> iterate through it.

Then `split()` already returns an array of strings, so you don't have to do anything fancy.

```
let sArray = s.split(','); // type of: string[]
for (const sPart of sArray) { // iterate
  console.log(sPart);
}
```